# JQuery requests working on one system but not on other systems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code of my admin page. Earlier this code used to work on my system. But now it ain't working anymore. My client needs to update this page and now when I tried running this page it does not perform JQuery requests.
What it does is on focus or change of value of first dropdown other category and subcategory dropdown gets updated by making Jquery requests to another php file which returns the category values. Also just to mention, I tried to run this page in different browsers with no success.

*Also facing issue in posting the code through code snippet* So writing the code right here..

The code is below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cracktitude-Admin</title>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "admin-adddata.php",
            data: data
            }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script> 
        function categorylist(str) 
        { 
        if (str=="") 
          { 
          document.getElementById("category").innerHTML=""; 
          return; 
          }  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
          } 
        else 
          {// code for IE6, IE5 
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
          } 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
          { 
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            { 
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } 
          } 
        xmlhttp.open("GET","admin-getdata.php?choice="+str,true); 
        xmlhttp.send(); 
        } 
    </script>

    <script>

        function subcategorylist(str1) 
        { 
        if (str1=="") 
          { 
          document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=""; 
          return; 
          }  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
          } 
        else 
          {// code for IE6, IE5 
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
          } 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
          { 
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            { 
            document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } 
          } 
        xmlhttp.open("GET","admin-getdata1.php?choice="+str1,true); 
        xmlhttp.send(); 
        } 
    </script> 

<style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
}

ul, ol, dl { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;}
a img { 
    border: none;
}

a:link {
    color: #42413C;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}


.content {

    padding: 10px 0;
}

.fltrt {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat {
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

form{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#333; 
}

form p{
    vertical-align:top;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Admin Panel</h1>

    <form>
      <p>Section:
        <select name="section" id="section" tabindex="1" onchange="categorylist(this.value)" onfocus="categorylist(this.value)" autofocus="autofocus">
          <option value="Aptitude">Aptitude</option>
          <option value="1">Engineering</option>
          <option value="2">GK</option>
          <option value="3">Interview</option>
          <option value="4">Puzzle &amp; Mind Games</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>Question: 
        <textarea name="question" id="question" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2" required="required"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>Option A: 
        <input type="text" name="optiona" id="optiona" required="required"/>
      </p>
      <p>Option B: 
        <input type="text" name="optionb" id="optionb" required="required"/>
      </p>
      <p>Option C: 
  <input type="text" name="optionc" id="optionc" required="required"/>
      </p>
      <p>Option D: 
        <input type="text" name="optiond" id="optiond" required="required" />
      </p>
      <p>Correct Answer: 
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" id="answer_0" />
          Option A |</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" id="answer_1" />
        Option B |</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" id="answer_2" />
        Option C |</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" id="answer_3" />
        Option D</label>
        <br />
      </p>
      <p>Explanation: 
        <textarea name="explanation" id="explanation" cols="45" rows="5"  required="required"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>Category: 
        <span name="category" id="category">
            <select name="cat">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>Sub-category: 
        <span name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
            <select name="subcat">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>Type: 
        <select name="type" id="type">
          <option value="1">I</option>
          <option value="2">II</option>
          <option value="3">III</option>
          <option value="4">IV</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add" /> 
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p>
    </form>
    </div>
  <!-- end .container -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 debug Network panel to see what is being sent and what the response is from the server. Your php url is relative to the current page, so it must be in the same location.

Comment: Suggestion: Do not use attribute based handlers (like `onchange=`) to connect events when using jQuery. jQuery's alternatives, like `$('#section').change(function(){...});`, are much cleaner and keep the handler with the code.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery ajax with vanilla JS ajax requests? Choose one and stick to it.

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie for your tips. I will try those.

Comment: Thank you @Novocaine for your comment. But I'm really not much into JQuery so... :( But will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from comments, this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4s4d1qgu/1/

Rather than use `onchange=` and `onfocus=` attribute handlers in the HTML, use jQuery to connect the events to your controls. e.g. like this:

```
$('#section').on('focus change', function () {
    var str = $(this).val();
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "admin-getdata.php?choice=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

If you view the console (in say Chrome), you will see the `php` *is* being called in the current directory, so please ensure your page is in the same folder as the `admin-adddata.php` & `admin-getdata.php` files. Use a tool like Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 debug Network panel to see what is being sent and what the response is from the server. It may be as simple as a 404 (not found).

Comment: Well, I tried your code buddy with no success! I feel the problem isn't with the code. I tried on different machine and it works. Also, different browsers on my system has failed to execute as desired.
I don't understand how this problem started. It seems the problem is with my system now as this code used to run well earlier on my system.

Comment: @Chandan Jha: Have you tried the F12 Network tool as suggested? What was the network response?

Comment: I tried F12 response...
It doesn't show error. But the responses are as follows-
admin.php -> Status: 206
Jquery.min.js -> Status: 304
injected.js -> Status: 200
content.min.css -> Status: 200

Comment: Some errors that I see-

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function admin.php:24 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function admin.php:9
Uncaught ReferenceError: categorylist is not defined

Comment: If you were using all my changes it would not be looking for `categorylist` as I removed that from the attributes. Are you able to share a link to a live site so I can tell you what is (still?) wrong with the page? You can email me via my website link if you prefer.

Comment: OK I only used the Jquery code that you have posted here. Let me check for all the code from the JSFiddle link you have posted. I will write back soon! :)

Comment: Basically just remove the `onfocus` and `onchange` attributes. That was the only change to the HTML.

Comment: It was my mistake. Now the 3rd error is gone. First two error still exists. My site isn't live yet. I can send you the project pages on email if you don't mind.

Comment: Contact me via my website contact page first. I don't want any (more) spam by posting it here :)

Comment: I left a message through your website.
Do check it mate!

Comment: Checked email and replied last night. Please send details to the email address provided.